# Google OCR working on specific area

Tags: android, android-camera, ocr, surfaceview

I am currently using a `SurfaceView` and `CameraSource` from `com.google.android.gms.vision` to capture detected text on the image, but since it captures everything on the `SurfaceView` area, I need to discard some of the recovered things.

The goal is making the `SurfaceView` to work like in the next image, ignoring all detected text in red crossed area, and giving to me only the things on the blue square.

Is this even possible?

[image: SurfaceView working goal]

Here is the layout (nothing special):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_surface"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here you have the OCR related code on the class:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private StringBuilder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_surface);

        TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        if (recognizer.isOperational()) {

            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), recognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .setRequestedFps(15.0f)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 100);
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                    //
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    cameraSource.stop();
                }
            });
            recognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {
                    //
                }

                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                    final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                    if (items.size() != 0) {
                        builder = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                            TextBlock it = items.valueAt(i);
                            builder.append(it.getValue());
                        }
                        String read = builder.toString().trim().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "");

                        //It continues doing other things here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    try {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry, but not with this approach. We ended up mixing this with OpenCV. You can select an exact area with that tool and use the OCR on it.

Comment: Ahhh that's sucks

Answer (score 0):

While the device is in portrait mode (like in your picture) the non-red-area should be a cropped piece of the Camera Preview (which fills the whole screen), so:

- if you want to show the whole Camera Preview and just execute OCR on the cropped area: then you have to get SurfaceView's "screenshot" (full area) and then crop that region to get desired pixels on-the-fly
- intead, if you want to JUST show the cropped area (because the red-area is filled with other interfaces, buttons, TextViews, etc..): then you have to play with SurfaceView to render only a desired piece of the Camera Preview in that specific place by playing with its Matrix parameter

I suggest you to "upgrade" to **TextureView** that is a bit more difficult to manage/use but allows cropping, zoommming and scaling the Preview as you want by using a Matrix on its internal Texture.

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

I'm trying to make minimal changes to your existing code, so just scan your whole image as you do now, and filter-out the resulting words (or blocks) that are out-of-bounds.

### Code

Find the `bounding-box` of a `word` and see if it is inside your `rectangle` (`rect`) using [rect.intersect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect):

```
Rect yourRect = new Rect(10, 20, 30, 40);
rect.intersect(yourRect);//also see Drawable d = d.getBounds();
```

Try adding this code to your `@Override public void receiveDetections()` method:

```
        //Loop through each `Block`
        foreach (TextBlock textBlock in blocks)
        {
            IList<IText> textLines = textBlock.Components; 

            //loop Through each `Line`
            foreach (IText currentLine in textLines)
            {
                IList<IText>  words = currentLine.Components;

                //Loop through each `Word`
                foreach (IText currentword in words)
                {
                    //Get the Rectangle/BoundingBox of the word
                    RectF rect = new RectF(currentword.BoundingBox);

                   // Check if the word boundingBox is inside the area required

                  // using: rect.intersect(yourRect);
                  //...
                }
```

so it looks like this:

```
        recognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
                //
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (items.size() != 0) {
                    builder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        TextBlock it = items.valueAt(i);
                        builder.append(it.getValue());
                    }
                    String read = builder.toString().trim().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "");

        List<TextBlock> blocks = new List<TextBlock>();

        TextBlock myItem = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); ++i)
        {
            myItem = (TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i);

            //Add All TextBlocks to the `blocks` List
            blocks.Add(myItem);

        }

        //Loop through each `Block`
        foreach (TextBlock textBlock in blocks)
        {
            IList<IText> textLines = textBlock.Components; 

            //loop Through each `Line`
            foreach (IText currentLine in textLines)
            {
                IList<IText>  words = currentLine.Components;

                //Loop through each `Word`
                foreach (IText currentword in words)
                {
                    //Get the Rectangle/BoundingBox of the word
                    RectF rect = new RectF(currentword.BoundingBox);

                   // Check if the word boundingBox is inside the area required

                  // using: rect.intersect(yourRect);
                  //put the word in a filtered list...
                }

            }

                    //It continues doing other things here
                }
            }
        });
```

Only six lines of code!